# Envio de e-mail com Codeigniter utilizando Gmail

Tags: codeigniter

Estou tentando fazer um formulário para envio de email porém recebo o seguinte erro:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.googlemail.com:465 (Connection timed out)
```

Criei um arquivo de configuração na pasta application/config chamado email.php com o seguinte código:

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| EMAIL CONFING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------
| Configuration of outgoing mail server.
| */
$config['protocol']='smtp';
$config['smtp_host']='ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
$config['smtp_port']='465';
$config['smtp_timeout']='30';
$config['smtp_user']='username@gmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass']='password';
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['newline']="\r\n";

/* End of file email.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/email.php */
```

E meu controller está da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Email extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
            #pega os dados enviado via post
            $contato = $this->input->post('contato');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $mensagem = $this->input->post('mensagem');

            $this->load->library('email');

            #envio do e-mail
            $this->email->from('usermail@gmail.com');
            $this->email->to('usermail@gmail.com');
            $this->email->subject('Dúvida enviada através do site');
            $this->email->message('Email resposta: '.$email.'<br /> Mensagem:<br />'.$mensagem);
            if($this->email->send()){
                echo 'E-mail enviado';
            } else {
                show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
            }
    }

}

/* End of file Email.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/Email.php */
```

Uso sistema operacional Ubuntu 14.04, nginx, phpfpm.

Se alguém puder ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Comment: você está utilizando servidor local?

Comment: isto, servidor local

Comment: então você vai precisar configurar o servidor local para o envio de emails, da uma pesquisada em sendmail que é uma boa ferramenta para isso

Answer (score 1):

Verifique se as configurações de envio de e-mail do seu `php.ini` estão habilitadas para o envio de email via ssl retirando o comentário da seguinte instrução:

`extension=php_openssl.so`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487649/setting-up-emails-in-code-igniter-2-02